# How can a Play controller uploading a multipartFormData provide progress to the client?

Tags: playframework

I have a Play 2.4.2 action that uploads a MultipartFormData successfully without issue using standard APIs (example below).  The frontend is an Angular app using directives to upload the file.  This Angular library also supports receiving progress on the file load from the server.

How would I accomplish this in my Play action?  Would I have to write a new body parser?

Here is my action which works but does not provide upload progress:

```
def uploadFile = Action(BodyParsers.parse.multipartFormData) { implicit req =>
    val fileName = req.body.file("file").map{ file =>
        val uploadDir = play.api.Play.current.configuration.getString("upload.dir").get
        file.ref.moveTo(play.api.Play.getFile(uploadDir + "/image." + file.filename))
        file.filename
    }
    Ok(Json.toJson(Map("status" -> "success", "file" -> fileName.get)))
}
```